# Infer types from reducer function

Tags: typescript

I have a reducer type that is based on 2-3 types. The `Store`, the `ReturnStore`, and the `Context` which is `void` by default.

How can I reuse the `CountReducer` type as type parameter in the `Action` type?

Right now, `Action` requires the same 2-3 types that `CountReducer` does, creating duplicate code, and makes the API confusing.

Current code:

```
type CountingStore = {
  state: "counting";
  ctx: number;
};

type Store = StartedStore | CountingStore | EndedStore;

type CountReducer = (s: Store, toAdd: number) => CountingStore;

const CountReducer: CountReducer = (s, toAdd) => ({
  state: "counting",
  ctx: s.ctx + toAdd
});
```

```
type Action<Store, ReturnStore, Context = void> = {
  act: (() => void) | ((ctx: Context) => void);
  stream: Observable<Context>;
  reducer: Reducer<Store, ReturnStore, Context>;
};
```

```
type Actions = {
  count: Action<Store, CountingStore, number>;
  end: Action<Store, EndedStore>;
  restart: Action<Store, StartedStore>;
};
```

Possible future API design:

```
type Action<MyReducer extends Reducer> = "???";
```

You can find the relevant source code in a runnable project here: https://github.com/marcusnielsen/rx-machine/blob/master/src/index.test.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional types to extract the type parameters from the reducer functions:

```
type ActionFromReducer<T extends (s: any, ctx?: any) => any> =  
  T extends (s: infer TStore, ctx: infer TContext) => infer TReturnStore ? Action<TStore, TReturnStore, TContext> : 
  T extends (s: infer TStore) => infer TReturnStore ? Action<TStore, TReturnStore, > : 
  never;
type Actions = {
  count: ActionFromReducer<CountReducer>;
  end: ActionFromReducer<EndReducer>;
  restart: ActionFromReducer<RestartReducer>;
};
```

Comment: I did have to change the order so the single-argument reducer comes before the two-argument reducer. Otherwise it caused the two-argument reducer to pattern match every time, and making the second argument `unknown` when matching a single-argument reducer as input.